# Magento: get rid off bullet points in menu

Tags: php, css, magento

[This is what it looks like](http://imgur.com/a/3CEtw)

First, I've tried going into style.css and adding

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none !important;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Did this with li as well but it didn't do anything. I'm thinking maybe it's not css but being printed out by php or something. Anyone know how I can get rid of these bullet points?

edit: it's definitely not css, when I added

```
list-style-type: circle;
```

It added an additional dot before the bullet points. So it has to be in the php or somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using this (which it's correct):

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

You may fix it, but be careful, you may want to use again `<li>` on your content but will not see the dots. The right solution will be to put the class specification before `ul & li`

```
.classname ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.classname li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

`.classname` will be the class of footer widget (depending on your image) or whatever you want to edit the list style.

Comment: The reason I did it that way was because I was frustrated and wanted to make sure if those were actually list-types. Turned out they're not...

Comment: As long as it is a public question, other people might have the same problem and may found very helpful your question but when they follow the answer (which is correct) but they may cause problems elsewhere. That's it :D

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
}
```